# OCR and Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, ocr

I create an OCR tool (optical character recognition) to test different OCR services, I want to write many tests to analyze which OCR service is the best. But Unit Test requires the exact coincidence, so, test is success or fail. I want to see percent of coincidence for each Unit test. Is it possible?

Comment: With a unit test you check if a single operation with mocked dependencies is doing what it is supposed to do. And there is no maybe but only true or false. You want to have some quality/performance test but you cannot do that with a framework for unit tests.

Comment: which framework should I use for it?